# Appending List Items to Dictionary, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with the following items

```
print(List)
['x, y, z', '1, 2, 3', '2, 4, 6', '4, 8, 12']
```

and a dictionary containing three empty lists

```
print(Dictionary)
{0: [], 1: [], 2: []}
```

Now I want to split each of the items into separate lists

```
print(List1)
['x', 'y', 'z']

print(List2)
['1', '2', '3']

and so forth..
```

and then append each item in the new lists to the dictionary so that

```
print(Dictionary)
{0: ['x', '1', '2', '4'], 1: ['y', '2', '4', '8'], 2: ['z', '3', '6', '12']}
```

Answer (score 1):

With help of `itertools`:

```
l = ['x, y, z', '1, 2, 3', '2, 4, 6', '4, 8, 12']
d = {0: [], 1: [], 2: []}

from itertools import chain

for idx, val in zip(sorted(d.keys()), zip(*chain.from_iterable([v.split(', ')] for v in l))):
    d[idx].extend(val)

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{0: ['x', '1', '2', '4'], 1: ['y', '2', '4', '8'], 2: ['z', '3', '6', '12']}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. get list from str in `lists`. I remove space and split it by `,`.
2. I used `key` of `dictionaries` as an index of each list.

```
lists = ['x, y, z', '1, 2, 3', '2, 4, 6', '4, 8, 12']
dictionaries = {0: [], 1: [], 2: []}

lists = [x.replace(' ', '').split(',') for x in lists]
for key in dictionaries.keys():
    dictionaries[key] = [x[key] for x in lists]

print (dictionaries)
```

The result is:

```
{0: ['x', '1', '2', '4'], 1: ['y', '2', '4', '8'], 2: ['z', '3', '6', '12']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution

```
lst = ['x, y, z', '1, 2, 3', '2, 4, 6', '4, 8, 12']
dct = {0: [], 1: [], 2: []}

letters = lst[0].split(', ')

for key in dct:
  numbers = lst[key + 1].split(', ')

  dct[key].append(letters[key])
  dct[key].extend(numbers)

print(dct)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oneshot way

```
import re

def dictChunker(content):
    chunker = {}
    for element in content:
        splittedElements = re.findall(r'\w+', element)
        for i in range(len(splittedElements)):
            chunker.setdefault(i, []).append(splittedElements[i])
    return chunker
```

```
>>> L = ['x, y, z', '1, 2, 3', '2, 4, 6', '4, 8, 12']
>>> dictChunker(L)
{0: ['x', '1', '2', '4'], 1: ['y', '2', '4', '8'], 2: ['z', '3', '6', '12']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner using list/dictionary comprehension and zip():

```
lst= ['x, y, z', '1, 2, 3', '2, 4, 6', '4, 8, 12']

dct = { i:v for i,v in enumerate(zip(*(s.split(", ") for s in lst))) }

# {0: ['x', '1', '2', '4'], 1: ['y', '2', '4', '8'], 2: ['z', '3', '6', '12']}
```

If you don't mind tuples instead of lists for the dictionary values:

```
dct = dict(enumerate(zip(*(s.split(", ") for s in lst))))

# {0: ('x', '1', '2', '4'), 1: ('y', '2', '4', '8'), 2: ('z', '3', '6', '12')}
```